# How to split a messed-up-dump back to separated files?

Tags: linux, shell, unzip

I have a ZIP file, not succeeded to unzip for some-reason, saying "invalid or incomplete multibytes or wide character". So I *unzip -p myfile.zip > Messed.data* , I want to separate them, with script.

1. *unzip -l* to get the files-size.
2. *dd ibs=1 skip=$((sum of front file-size)) count=$((this-file-size))*

**I tried and found the speed was unbearable slow.**

So I ask for any help to this. Thank you.

Comment: Could be that the "multibyte" message is only a warning about filenames? Maybe it still managed to uncompress all files, just using some strange filenames, to be renamed.

Comment: yes，I uncompressed all files into a single one, so it's able to uncompress. I tried "unzip -O 'somecodepage-balabala'", but nothing out.  Maybe there is some parameters to rename filename while unzipping, but get no idea.

Comment: No I mean the original plain `unzip myfile.zip` command. Doesn't it write  any files? See also `man unzip` options `-U`, `-UU` or  `-^`.